# Align text vertically using rad tab strip asp.net telerik

Tags: css, telerik, orientation, vertical-alignment, rad-controls

I am looking for a way to align my rad tab strips.Generally I used to align them horizontally like this:

```
---\    ---\     ------\
One \   |Two\    | Three|
----   -----     ------
```

But now my requirement is like this:

```
O-|
n |- This is one tab.It occupies the complete div.As in, the space you see below for two and     three.
e-|

T
w
o

T
h
r
e
e
```

How do I achieve that using rad controls and asp.net? When I set the orientation as vertical left I am ending up something like this

```
One
Two
Three
```

Some of my code is :

```
 <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="radCustInfo" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="outerMultiPage">
                            <telerik:RadPageView ID="radCustInfoPage" runat="server">
                                <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="radCustInfoTab" runat="server" MultiPageID="radMultiPageCustInfo"
                                    SelectedIndex="0" Orientation="VerticalLeft" Width="30px" Height="150px" Align="Left">
                                    <Tabs>
                                        <telerik:RadTab ImageUrl="images/companyTabStrip.gif" Width="30px" height="55px" ></telerik:RadTab>                                            
                                        <telerik:RadTab ImageUrl="images/contactsTabStrip.gif" Width="30px" height="60px" ></telerik:RadTab>                                            
                                        <telerik:RadTab ImageUrl="images/notesTabStrip.gif" Width="30px" height="50px" ></telerik:RadTab>
                                    </Tabs>
                                </telerik:RadTabStrip>

                                <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="radMultiPageCustInfo" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="innerMultiPage">
                                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="PageView1" BackColor="White">  
                                        <table style="vertical-align:top; height:75px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="vertical-align: top; height: 75px; width:75px;">
                                                    <b class="infoTitle">Company:</b><br />
                                                    <asp:Literal ID="litCompany" runat="server" /><br />
                                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Edit Customer" Target="_blank" Visible="false" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="vertical-align: top; height: 100px;">
                                                    <div class="divAddress" style="height: 70px">
                                                        <b class="infoTitle">Address:</b><br />
                                                        <asp:Literal ID="litAddress" runat="server" /><br />
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>                                                                                 
                                    </telerik:RadPageView>
```

...etc
I used image and it does not look good. I have adjusted the css for rts rtsLink rtsLI etc,..but none seem to work. Can someone point me in the right direction?If you need more info, please ask.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `RadTabStrip` use Telerik `RadSpliiter`

Check out these demos to get started

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/sp_slidedirection/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  .box_rotate {
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
       -o-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
             filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
         -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
}
```

ASPX:

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="tab1" runat="server" Orientation="VerticalLeft">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab1" runat="server" CssClass="box_rotate">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab2" runat="server" CssClass="box_rotate">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab3" runat="server" CssClass="box_rotate">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab4" runat="server" CssClass="box_rotate">
                </telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
```